# How to get Sub objects based on value using linq?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

```
Top Tier Object
        SubTier Objects
            SubSubTier Objects 1.1,1.2,1.3 : SubTierId = 2
            SubSubTier Objects 2.1,2.2,1.3 : SubTierId = 3
        SubTier Objects
            SubSubTier Objects 3.1,3.2,3.3 : SubTierId = 1
            SubSubTier Objects 4.1,4.2,4.3 : SubTierId = 2
```

Expected end results is to get an IEnumerable with 1.2, 2.3, 3.1, 4.2 which represents the SubTierId of each subTier.

```
SubSubTiers mySubSubTier = allTiers.Select(topTier => 
            topTier.SubTiers.Where(sbTier => sbTier.Id == topTier.SubTierId));
```

but what happens is I get this return type.

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<SubSubTier>>
```

What is the best way so that I just get a single `IEnumerable` of the `SubSubTier`?

Comment: you can use SelectMany instead of Select

Comment: were my answer helpful? Do you have any other issues?

Comment: Yeah that did the trick just didn't get back rightaway. Thanks a bunch! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [SelectMany](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb534336(v=VS.110).aspx) instead of Select

```
SubSubTiers mySubSubTier = allTiers.SelectMany(topTier => 
        topTier.SubTiers.Where(sbTier => sbTier.Id == topTier.SubTierId));
```

it will select subtiers into combined `IEnumerable` instead of `IEnumerable` of `IEnumerables`